# Is this normal or should I be worried?

Tags: plumbing

The plumbing under my kitchen sink looks discolored and there is a black mark. I don't see any water leaking though.

[image: under sink]

Comment: That green discoloration is mildly toxic and should not gotten in eyes or skin, or ingested by skin-to-food contact, or by using a dishwashing sponge to clean it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The black mark is the result of a careless plumber nearly setting the kitchen on fire when installing that cutoff valve. If your place hasn't burned down by now, you can ignore the burnt spot.

The green discoloring is oxidation caused by a slow leak higher up on the pipe. Tiny leaks sometimes seal themselves via corrosion, so if you don't find any moisture on the pipe, this is another thing you can ignore.

If you want more peace of mind, you could clean the green oxidation from a visible section of the pipe and see if it reappears in a few weeks. Clean pipe = no worries.

If you want *less* peace of mind, consider this: if the installing plumber was careless enough to burn the wooden cabinet with his torch, and to leave a leak causing that much visible corrosion, what else might he have done incompetently? You may have sloppy plumbing throughout your house.

Welcome to your new home, and good luck.

Comment: +1, although I would suggest not ignoring the signs and symptoms of that leak, even if there is no moisture found. Absolutely choose A.I.'s "more peace of mind" option and find the source if you can.